# How to use label and input based React component multiple times without having the input values stay same for different questions on going to nextpage

Tags: reactjs, forms, dynamic

I am building a react app it has various components rendering together to make a form. The form is displayed one section at a time. but when i move to a new section the value i put in the previous section is still visible.

this is my component

```
import React from 'react'

import './SectionInput.css'

function SectionInput({label , placeholder, defaultValue, name, onChange, type})  {

        return (<div className='form-component'>
                
            <label>{label}
            <input placeholder={placeholder} defaultValue={defaultValue} name={name} onChange={onChange} type={type} />
            </label>
                
        </div>
        );

}

export default SectionInput
```

this is how i am using the component to make various sections

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Workspace.css'
import Sections from '../../Sections'
import SectionInput from '../SectionInput/SectionInput';

function Workspace() {

    const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(0);

    const [present, setPresent] = useState('No')

    const personal = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
        
        <div className='details'>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='What is your name?' placeholder='FirstName LastName' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Email ID' placeholder='example@abc.com' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Phone Number' placeholder='+914567891234' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='LinkedIn' placeholder='Enter profile link' />
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const summary = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Explain your goals, ambitions and why you are an asset in 1 or 2 sentences.' placeholder='summary' />
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const education = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
        <div className='details'>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='What School or University did you study in?' placeholder='' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='Which degree did you study for?' placeholder='Bachelors in Technology, Computer Sciences' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='For what duration did you study there(if still a student, add starting year to present)?' placeholder='July 1991 - May 1995' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='How much did you score(is still a student, add recent aggregate score)?' placeholder='CGPA: 7.9/10' />
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const skills = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
        <div className='details'>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='Give technical skills you possess relevant to the job.' placeholder='JavaScript, HTML, CSS, React' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='Give non-technical skills you possess relevant to the job.' placeholder='MS Word, Google Sheets' />
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const workXP = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
        <div className='details'>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='What position did you work at?' placeholder='Senior Product Manager' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='Which company did you work at?' placeholder='Pepsi Co' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='When did you start working here?' type='month'/>
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='When did you stop working here?' type='month'/>
            </div>
            <div >
                <SectionInput label='Explain how you had an effect on the team or the companny as a whole?(keep in mind -use action words to begin your sentences -show your impact through metrics -Write in pointers)' placeholder='Designed and wrote 30+ content pieces for marketing and community engagement.' />
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const projects = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
        <div className='details'>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='Name of your project' placeholder='Movie recommendation system' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='When did you start working on this project?' type='month' name='projects-end-date' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='When did you finish this project?' type='month'/>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Explain the project.(keep in mind -first write what the project is -state the tools used to maka it -then write the target use of it)?' placeholder='Developed a [what you built] using [languages, frameworks, APIs] that [what your project does in a couple of words].' />
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const extra = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='Name of your project' placeholder='Movie recommendation system' />
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='When did you start working here?' type='month'/>
            </div>
            <div className='detail-item'>
                <SectionInput label='When did you stop working here?' type='month'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Explain the project.(keep in mind -first write what the project is -state the tools used to maka it -then write the target use of it)?' placeholder='Developed a [what you built] using [languages, frameworks, APIs] that [what your project does in a couple of words].' />
            </div>

        </div>
    )

    const achievements = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Section Title' defaultValue={Sections[currentSection].title} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <SectionInput label='Any notbale recognition received.(awards, scholarships)' placeholder='2020: Linkedin Scholarship Winner (1 of 1200 of 17000 selected)' />
            </div>

        </div>
    )


    const selectSectionInput = () => {
        switch(Sections[currentSection].title){
            case Sections[0].title :
                return personal;
            case Sections[1].title:
                return summary;
            case Sections[2].title :
                return education;
            case Sections[3].title :
                return skills;
            case Sections[4].title :
                return workXP;
            case Sections[5].title :
                return projects;
            case Sections[6].title :
                return extra;
            case Sections[7].title :
                return achievements;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


    const NextButtonClick = () => {
        const nextQuestion = currentSection + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < Sections.length) {
            setCurrentSection(nextQuestion);
        } else {
            alert('you reached the end of the quiz');
        }
    }

    return <div>
        <h2>{Sections[currentSection].title}</h2>
        
        <div >
        <form>

            <div className='each-section'>

                {selectSectionInput()}
            </div>

        </form>
        <button onClick={() => NextButtonClick()}>Next <img width="25rem" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/96/right.png" alt="right"/></button>
        </div>

        
    </div>
}

export default Workspace
```

sections

```
const Sections = [
    {
        title: 'Personal Information',
    },
    {
        title: 'Summary',
    },
    {
        title: 'Education',
    },
    {
        title: 'Skills',
    },
    {
        title: 'Work Experience',
    },
    {
        title: 'Projects',
    },
    {
        title: 'Extra Curriculars',
    },
    {
        title: 'Achievements'
    }
]

export default Sections
```

and my output looks something like this with error

[when i fill in the data in one section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFMYh.png)

[some of it carries forward to the next section without me entering anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzmNf.png)

even the section title doesn't change remains the same tho the next button should change it

Comment: Could you show the full component?

Comment: which component?

Comment: The one with sections

Comment: I have edited it in

Comment: Either add a `key` prop to each parent div of a section e.g. `<div key="summary">` or create a new component from each section

Comment: do i need to generate key for all the objects in sections for that

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use state, you can create either for each section a component or have a section component that dynamically show the right one.

using state it will refresh the data on the UI and show you the right behaviour.

Comment: can you give me a small example of how to do that
i am completely new to react

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).